# Visualforce page URL with embedded login details

Tags: visualforce, url

I know how to provide URL to Salesforce.com instance with embedded login details by using this structure:

```
https://servername.com?pw=qwerty&un=myname%40example.com
```

Now the question is how to provide URL with login details to VF page?
Could it be achieved using similar URL structure?

My VF page URL is something similar to this:

```
https://servername.com/apex/VF_Page?param=true
```

Comment: it would be vulnerable to security...

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is it possible?

Comment: You want to provide login details to Salesforce in a Visualforce page that is already in Salesforce? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Jesse: I want to have URL which could be entered in browser and the page would show up without logging to Salesforce instance. I want it to be done automatically, everyday, that's why I don't want to enter login details. VF page will be shown only within the company, automatically, without human interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do by including a startURL parameter.

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?pw=qwerty&un=myname%40example.com&startURL=%2Fapex%2FVF_Page%3Fparam%3Dtrue
```

Comment: Aa, startURL.. Thanks Daniel, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve